# Query custom fields on a custom taxonomy?

Tags: php, mysql, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress

I've scoured the WP Codex, SO, and Google, and was unable to find a way to do this using "the Wordpress way."

I'm simply trying to write a query to filter all taxonomy terms of a custom taxonomy by a custom field of that taxonomy. For instance, I have a custom taxonomy called "People" and, using the [ACF plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/), I created custom fields called "Age" and "Eye Color". I want to query the WP DB by getting the oldest person in the database that has "brown" as their eye color. The [relevant WP_Query documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) focuses mostly on posts and other types but does not provide for querying by *taxonomy* meta fields.

Is there a "Wordpress way" to do this, or should I just write the raw SQL and move on with my life?

Answer (score 0):

If you can come back to this code in six months or so, just writing the query in SQL may be fine. But be aware that the WP core team is in the process of retiring the old and nasty "mysql_" database APIs, so your code may require revisiting.

But the point about getting on with your life is well-taken.

You can probably do this the WP way. Look at this page. http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries especially the third example.  You can use the posts_join filter to add an arbitrarily complex series of JOINs to the query. That you can use

Similarly, you can use the posts_where, posts_orderby, and posts_limits filters to modify the query to get the item you're seeking.